# Don't know how to build task 'action text:install'

Tags: ruby-on-rails, actiontext

In my Rails 6 app I try to install action_text with:

```
    rails action_text:install
```

but I get:

```
Don't know how to build task 'action_text:install'
```

My rails 6 app was builded with:

```
rails new keeper --skip-test --skip-bundle --database=postgresql --skip-turbolinks --skip-active-storage
```

config/application.rb

```rb
require_relative 'boot'
require_relative 'app_config'
require_relative 'spider_options'

require "rails"
# Pick the frameworks you want:
require "active_model/railtie"
require "active_job/railtie"
require "active_record/railtie"
require "action_controller/railtie"
require "action_mailer/railtie"
require "active_storage/engine"
# require "action_mailbox/engine"
# require "action_view/railtie"
require "action_cable/engine"
require "sprockets/railtie"
# require "rails/test_unit/railtie"

# Require the gems listed in Gemfile, including any gems
# you've limited to :test, :development, or :production.
Bundler.require(*Rails.groups)
```

Any ideas why is this happening?

Thank you in advance

Comment: What does your `config/application.rb` file look like?

Comment: Dear @hashrocket I updated my q with application.rb ,,,,

Comment: When I replace all the require statements in application.rb with: require 'rails/all' the bin/rails action_text:install worked ok...

Answer (score 9, accepted):

When I replace all the require statements in application.rb with:

```rb
require 'rails/all'
```

the `bin/rails action_text:install` worked ok

Comment: you can just add `require 'action_text/engine'`